# Why are there separate comparison functions/operators for strings and numbers?

Tags: generics, polymorphism, scheme, operators, lisp

I'm slowly learning Scheme and revising Haskell by reading the online tutorial [Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours). I've just gotten up to [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Evaluation,_Part_2) part, where it introduces us to some of the comparison operators in Scheme.

```
("=", numBoolBinop (==)),
("<", numBoolBinop (<)),
(">", numBoolBinop (>)),
("/=", numBoolBinop (/=)),
(">=", numBoolBinop (>=)),
("<=", numBoolBinop (<=)),
("&&", boolBoolBinop (&&)),
("||", boolBoolBinop (||)),
("string=?", strBoolBinop (==)),
("string<?", strBoolBinop (<)),
("string>?", strBoolBinop (>)),
("string<=?", strBoolBinop (<=)),
("string>=?", strBoolBinop (>=)),
```

I have a couple of newbie questions.
1. Why are there separate comparison operators for different types, rather than one generic operator or one operator which has many overloads?
2. Is it possible to have a "generic" equality operator which works for all types and how would it be implemented? if not for all types, then at least for strings and numbers?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second question only: no, it is not.  For a start there is a difference between the `eq?` and any other equality predicate, and `eq?` almost inevitably has unreliable behaviour for numbers.  So you need at least `eq?` and a 'semantic' equality predicate.  But such a semantic equality predicate can't exist because the language can't know what semantics you intend.  For instance, what should this return?

```
(let ([c (cons #f #f)])
  (let ([a (cons c c)]
        [b (cons (cons #f #f) (cons #f #f))])
    (general-semantic-equal? a b)))
```

Well, whether it should return true or false depends on whether it *matters in the program* that the car and cdr of `a` are `eq?` while those of `b` are not.  And that question is not one that can be answered without knowing what the program is doing: equality predicates are application-dependent and the best the language can do is to provide a toolkit which allows you to build one.

Answer (score 0):

Scheme has disjoint types and decided not to make generic comparison. The reason can be

1. The standards don't have any method override
2. Historically, we use `string-ref` or `vector-ref` like stuffs instead of one generic `ref`.

So it's rather natural it doesn't have generic comparison procedures. The only exception is the number comparison procedures.

As I mentioned above Scheme standards don't have any method override mechanism however tt's not possible to make generic procedures. You just need to built them atop other object oriented libraries such as Tiny CLOS.

If you only need them for strings and numbers, you can also do something like this:

```
(define (generic= n/s1 n/s2 . rest)
  (cond ((for-all number? (cons* n/s1 n/s2 rest))
         (apply = n/s1 n/s2 rest))
        ((for-all string? (cons* n/s1 n/s2 rest))
         (apply string=? n/s1 n/s2 rest))
        (else (assertion-violation 'generic= "type not supported"))))
```